# Making CardView width match parent even when elevation > 0

Tags: android, android-layout

I wanted a cardview similar to this:

[image]

I wanted my CardView separated like that. The problem is, I don't know how to make CardView go edge to edge or match the width of the CardView to its parent. If I put shadows or setting the elevation at 4dp/8dp, the entire CardView adjusts to show the shadows on both end. Which is not what I want. This is worse when viewed on pre-lollipop.

I am believing this is just thick line separating it which can be done creating custom view with a custom drawable. But can this be done with just CardViews? I need my CardViews to go to the most edge and show separation at the bottom.

Here is my current layout. I created a separate layout file for each CardViews and included them in my fragment like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.neonwarge.android.notifire.activity.TaskActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        layout="@layout/cardview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <include
        layout="@layout/cardview2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        ....

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is what generally a CardView looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

            ...

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</merge>
```

Comment: Did you get the solution ?? Even i am searching for the same

Comment: @dev Nope not yet, I abandoned this idea. But I have a project where I use shadow as a .png and plug it into a View as background. Position it using `RelativeLayout` `layout_bottom`  and voila. 

The good thing about it is that its very straightforward and the material design guidelines have specs on how to draw the shadows so you can tweak this using your favorite photo creation/manipulation software.

What I hate about this is that, I need to have an extra view nested in my layout just to show shadows but its a quick solution though.